# Работа с исключениями

Tags: c#, исключения

Подскажите, как в случае попадания на исключения вернуться к повторному набиранию числа?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
        try
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Format exception!");
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool keepAsking = true;
while (keepAsking)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
    try
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        keepAsking = false;
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Format exception!");
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
bool keepAsking = true;
while (keepAsking)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
    int i; 
    keepAsking = !Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);
    if (keepAsking)
        Console.WriteLine("Format exception!");
}
```

Comment: можете объяснить , почему происходит возврат к команде Console.WriteLine("Enter number: "); ?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor В первом варианте в случае ошибки кидает на исключение раньше, чем изменится `keepAsking = false`. А во втором `Int32.TryParse` возвращает `true` если параметр успешно преобразован, иначе `false`, при этом в случае ошибки не кидает исключение, а `i` становится `null`.